# How do I preselect value in semantic_form_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I'm building a rails project, I have two models: User and Attachment. User has many attachments. One of the columns for the Attachment is salutation, and it can be `mr` or `mrs` (enum attributes 0 and 1).

In my ActiveAdmin, when I create a user, I have a dropdown where I can select one of the two options. The selected value is empty. I want to make the `mr` value preselected.

I tried this but it doesn't work:

```
<%= semantic_form_for [:admin, user], builder: ActiveAdmin::FormBuilder do |f| %>
    <% f.has_many :attributes, heading:false do |g| %>
        <% g.input :salutation, value: 'mr' %>
    <% end%>
<%= f.actions%>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I never used semantic_form_for, but `selected: 'mr'` is not working?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try with:

```
g.input :salutation, input_html: { value: 'mr' }
```